# Ajuda com string e libcurl c++

Tags: c++

Boa noite.

Esta e a primeira vez que publico algo aqui, Gostaria de ajuda com um programa que estou fazendo para agilizar alguns processos la no trabalho, não sou programador estou apenas aprendendo ja busquei em varios lugares mas não encontrei resposta,

```
    int contagem = 05;
    while( contagem < 15 ){


{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {



        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://teste.teste/upload.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "senha=****&loja=**&pdv=" << contagem );
```

gostaria de colocar pdv = a variavel contagem, para executar em varios caixa automatico.

<< contagem ); desta forma não esta dando certo.

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, bem vindo ao Sopt! Se possível tente detalhar melhor sua dúvida, principalmente nesse parágrafo, ficou confuso: *gostaria de colocar pdv = a variavel contagem, para executar em varios caixa automatico.
<< contagem ); desta forma não esta dando certo.*. Qual sua experiência com `C++`? Recomendo uma experiência mínima, principalmente por ser essa linguagem ;)

Comment: Estou aprendendo agora a linguagem c++, gostaria que sempre que rodado o programa o post do curl fosse com um valor de pdv diferente uma sequencia de 5 a 15